# Map visualization based on occurrences of ZIP codes

Tags: overlay, zip-codes

I have an array of ZIP codes (from Poland) in CSV format. Some of the ZIP codes are repeated more often than the others.

I would like to visualize them all on a map, emphasizing (with colors e.g.) the ones which are occurring more often. Similar to the approach in the image below.

[image: Map with emphasized parts based on occurences of a zip code]

Comment: Which software do you use?

Comment: @babel Actually I am looking for software proposal which would solve the problem.

Comment: A software proposal does not yet resolve the problem... So what can you use, where have you access to? I would recomand QGIS

Comment: OK, assuming I'd take QGIS: is there a way to do it there?

Comment: What exactly is in your CSV file and do you have geodata of ZIP codes?

Comment: 1. Get data with polygons of the ZIP-code zones (OpenStreetMap/OverpassTurbo or gadm.org might be worth looking), 2. Load and join the polygons and the ZIP-layers. 3. Create an attrribute with an aggregation function, grouped by zip-codes and get the sum. 4. Apply a categorized or graduated layer symbology. I suggest to proceed step by step and ask separate questions when you're stuck.

Comment: @bugmenot123 I don't have any geodata. I just have an array of codes like (53214;54321;....) and I know that they are from Poland.

Comment: Thank you @Babel, I will give it a try!